# Comparing the values of two variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, python-requests

No matter if I enter the correct number, it still returns “Try again”. How can I rectify this?

```
import random
from random import randint
num = randint(1000, 9999) 

print (num)

while True:
    guess = input ("Please guess a four digit number. ")
    print (guess)

if guess == num:
    print ("Well Done!")
else:
    print ("Try again")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mureinik is correct about the fact that strings cannot be compared with integers, but I'd like to clarify that int() can explode on you (figuratively) if the function does not receive numbers.

To remedy this, put the contents of the while loop into a try statement:

```
import random
num = random.randint(1000, 9999)

print (num)

while True:
    try: 
        guess = input("Please guess a four digit number.")
        print(guess)
        if int(guess) == num:
            print ("Well Done!")
        else:
            print ("Try again")
    except ValueError:
        print ("Input is not an integer. Redo!")
```

Comment: Do *not* use bare except clauses.

Comment: Thx, I’ll try that.

Answer (score 5):

Your `num` is an int while the inputted guess is a string, so they can never be equal. If you wish to compare them, you should make sure they're both from the same type

E.g., use only strings:

```
num = str(randint(1000, 9999))
```

or convert the user's guess to an int:

```
guess = int(input("Please guess a four digit number. "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't convert the user input into an integer. You're comparing an integer and a string.

```
from random import randint as rn

while 1:
 print ('Well Done!' if int(input('Please guess a four digit number. ')) is rn(1000, 9999) else 'Try again')
```